# Postgresql, select empty fields

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get empty "text" fields from my table which I cleared manually with pgadmin.
Initially in those fields was '' and I can query them like this:

```
SELECT mystr, mystr1 FROM mytable WHERE mystr='' or mystr1=''
```

But that not work if I delete text from them and leave cells blank.

How to write query to get those '' and clear cells together in result?
Or clear cells alone?

Comment: Are the strings empty or NULL? (in postgres `''` and `NULL` are different)

Comment: I don't know what 'type of blank cell' is this, just deleted all text of cell with pgadmin. Now I try to query WHERE mystr=NULL OR mystr1=NULL, and didn't get result out.

Comment: You cannot compare to NULL, NULL is not a value, it is orthogonal. You should use `WHERE mystr IS NULL` instead.

Comment: Hm, "WHERE mystr='' OR mystr IS NULL OR mystr1='' OR mystr1 IS NULL" still dont find all empty fields. What I do wrong? Should I use some brackets here? Actually, this returns again only cells which have '' inside.

Comment: Please note that a `'` or `"` is a valid character inside a string. So a string *could* consist of only one or two quote characters.

Comment: Of course. But still can't get results from empty or "empty" cells (rows). Actually, I am trying to find which rows contain empty cells.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
SELECT mystr, mystr1 
FROM mytable 
WHERE COALESCE(mystr, '') = '' 
   OR COALESCE(mystr1, '') = ''
    ;
```

Explanation: the `coalesce(a,b,c, ...)` function traverses the list `a,b,c,...` from left to right and stops at the first non-null element. `a,b,c` can be any expression (or constant), but must yield the same type (or be coercable to the same type).

Comment: Thank you "wildplasser", never see such expression or command. I have to examine this carefully. This still don't find my empty cells. Luckily, by copying data to notepad I found that in those "empty" cells pgadmin leave one space (chr(32)). So WHERE mystr=' ' give results. Is here (in postgresql) some function like TRIM which can reject spaces from both sides of a string?

Comment: Yes, there is a TRIM() function. It is even ANSI-SQL (just like COALESCE() )

Comment: In a recent use case, I had to write my WHERE clause like this:
WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(parcelid), '')
The parcelid field was a VARCHAR(17) and I believe by default the data creators pad the column with spaces.