# How do i fetch NULL values in Postgreql and difference between NULL and NULL::Character varying?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I query the Postgres DB with `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE empty IS NULL` I get nothing, and I get all the rows when I use `WHERE empty = ''`.

It would seem then like Table Output will not convert your empties to nulls. Maybe you could convert nulls to empties exactly before the output.

Example:

```
select * from "Attendance_SwipeEffHrs" where "TimsyHrs" is null.
```

It shows 3 records. In other hand, if i use,

```
select * from "Attendance_SwipeEffHrs" where "TimsyHrs"=''.
```

It Shows 5 records. I did not insert empty records in the field. So how can i get all the records.

Comment: You could use: `where coalesce("TimsyHrs",'') = ''` to get both rows with empty values and `null` values.

Comment: hmm http://stackoverflow.com/a/14173419/905902

Comment: Or just do `where "TimsyHrs IS NULL OR TimsyHrs = ''`, the `COALESCE()` solution is pretty but it might not use the available indexes by default.